# React won't acknowledge my Context component as functional component. getting invalid hook call error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a simple context to toggle a drawer in my website and i'm facing this weird error where i'm getting an invalid hook call when trying to call useReducer for my context, i don't understand what's going on as i built multiple context components similar to this before and never faced this problem. what's wrong with my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useReducer } from 'react';

export const DrawerContext = React.createContext();

export function toggleDrawerDisplayAction(dispatch, currentDrawerState) {
    if (currentDrawerState == "none") {
        dispatch({ type: "SHOW_DRAWER", payload: "block" });
    } else {
        dispatch({ type: "HIDE_DRAWER", payload: "none" });
    }
}

export function HideDrawerAction(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: "HIDE_DRAWER", payload: "none" });
}

export function drawerReducer(state, action) {
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SHOW_DRAWER":
            return { currentDrawerState: action.payload };
        case "HIDE_DRAWER":
            return { currentDrawerState: action.payload };
        default:
            return { currentDrawerState: state };
    }
}

let DrawerContextProvider = function (props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(drawerReducer, {
        currentDrawerState: "none"
    })

    return (<DrawerContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
        {props.children}
    </DrawerContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default DrawerContextProvider;
```

the full error is as follows:

```
react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:16227:1)
    at useReducer (react.development.js:1626:1)
```

Comment: maybe try giving your component definition with const instead of let.

Comment: Nope, didn't work

Comment: Have you gone through the list of things to check from the error and rulled them out? Is the error definitely coming from `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer()` and not somewhere else?

Comment: For completeness, you should include how/where you are using `DrawerContextProvider`.

Comment: The error occurs when i try to call the "toggleDrawerDisplayAction" function from another component. weirdly enough that "HideDrawerAction" function gets called by default on each page and yet the error doesn't occur with it.

Comment: So it sounds like the error is actually coming from one of the components that are showed when you dispatch `SHOW_DRAWER` then... but since you're still failing to provide a [mre] it's just guessing.

Comment: i mean that could be the case, when i call HideDrawerAction function everything works and fires just fine, but when i call toggleDrawerDisplayAction nothing fires and i get the error, i tried console logging something in the function before dispatching anything and nothing is being logged, the function itself isn't running..i can't provide code where the functions are being called as that code is so long and messy, i gotta refactor it later

Answer (score 0):

Okay the issue was that i was importing the action function like this:

```
import toggleDrawerDisplayAction from "../contexts/DrawerContext";
```

while i should be importing it like this:

```
import {toggleDrawerDisplayAction} from "../contexts/DrawerContext";
```

i don't really understand why but this fixed the issue